# Attach curve to the character

Tags: animation, rigging, bezier-curves

I have a stylized character with a mouth made from curve. The curve has lots of shape keys, so the character could speak, smile, etc. The problem is I can not attach this curve to the face, so it moves properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved this one: apply "Child Of" constraint to the curve. Select body as the Target object. Create a vertex group with the facial vertexes and use it in the Child Of constraint.
Tap the Set Inverse button.
Done!

[image]